# Прилагательное или краткое прилагательное?

Tags: грамматика, прилагательные

Скажите пожалуйста знатоки, чем отличается употребление краткого прилагательного заместо прилагательного?

- Эти книги очень интересны и популярны среди читателей.
- Эти книги очень интересные и популярные среди читателей.

Или еще пример:

- Она очень красива и её внешность притягательна.
- Она очень красивая и её внешность притягательная.

Чем отличаются примеры друг от друга? Можно ли их взаимозаменить?

Comment: Ожидал увидеть "...и популярны среди читателей". Сейчас выходит что одни книги нравятся другим книгам.

Comment: @Artemix Изменим, спасибо за подсказку.

Comment: This question is a can of worms, imho. Some adjectives are interchangeable synonyms, some are not. For example, "Хороша" is "Beautiful", but "Хорошая" is "Good, nice". Usually the difference is subtle, full forms are bookish and short forms are colloquial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short adjectives are usually preferred  as predicatives, like in your sentences

> Эти книги популярны среди читателей.(you can't say интересны среди...)

Full forms are preferred in an attributive function.They are interchangeable in most(but not all) situations.And the emphasis is slightly different.

> У нее привлекательная внешность. Ее внешность привлекательна.Эти книги интересные.Книги интересны и тебе и мне.

Comment: Please explain then in the first sentence in what way would it be correct to say it?

Comment: Эти книги интересные/интересны ( more of a quality ), они очень популярны (популярные-- уже плохо) (function ) среди читателей.

Comment: I don't see any mistakes in "Эти книги очень интересны и популярны среди читателей". When I read it I didn't have any doubts that "среди читателей" refers to "популярны", and "интересны" is a standalone adjective.

Comment: Perhaps it's a personal perception but I still don't like this sentence,  because a constant quality is tied with a temporary one.

Comment: Related http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/13103/translation-for-when-i-was-young

Answer (score 1):

1) В русском языке нет слова "заместо" :).  Только "вместо".
2) Примеры отличаются друг от друга тем, что варианты с краткими прилагательными — это речь образованного человека. 
Чего нельзя сказать про  "эти книги популярные среди читателей", и "ее внешность привлекательная". Но слышать подобные фразы приходится часто.Слышать и читать на форумах в Интернете. В книгах их нет,  потому что книги редактируются

Answer (score 0):

Их можно заменять в большинстве случаев. Краткие прилагательные произошли от глаголов, а позже появились полные прилагательные. Разница, в общем случае, бывает в интонации, в эмоциях. Например: ты очень красивый - это произность дольше, поэтому здесь может быть какое-то чувство. Ты очень красив - звучит слегка небрежно. Однако разница редко бывает заметна