# Predicate taking instrumental case

Tags: падежи

When I use the verb 'быть' in the present, the predicate takes the nominative case, as in 'Я - высокий.' But when I change the tense, I sometimes feel I should use the instrumental instead (so 'Я был высокий' vs 'Я был высоким'). In what cases do I use each?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Case of complements in Russian](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/14182/case-of-complements-in-russian)

Comment: Read this https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/13103/translation-for-when-i-was-young

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, your question seems to be a duplicate of the other one that [had been previously asked](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/14182/case-of-complements-in-russian/14183#14183).

Quotation from my answer to the previous one:

***The difference is that быть + Instrumentalis is similar to a past perfective form (as a perfective action unrelated to a moment of utterance), while быть + Nominative would be compared to a present-perfective structure in a language where such a distinction exists.***

***As for the future tense, some decades or a century ago the phrase with Nominative compliment [будет журналист] might be equally correct, but nowadays it sounds as a little bit obsolete.***

***The usage of Instrumental as a copular compliment is similar to that of [Essive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essive_case) (a case of an impermanent state) in Balto-Fennic languages and can be regarded as a Fenno-Ugric substrate.***

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm new to the site and couldn't find the other question.

Comment: @FM22 There is one more on the more or less the same topic (preicate/complement in Instrumental VS Nominative)

Comment: If that's a Finno-Ugric substrate, then why instrumental is used with predicatives in Ukrainian and Polish? Were these languages also influenced by Finnic languages?

Comment: Any examples? Anyway, see the Balto-Slavo-Germanic theory, where a common Proto-Slavic language is likely to be influenced by a (Proto)-Balto-Fennic language.

Answer (score 3):

`Я был высоким` is grammar correct option because we can ask `я был (в прошлом) кем? - высоким человеком` and instrumental case asking the same questions `Кем? Чем?`
But the first option also can be used in speaking and writing, so it's not mistake just nuance. Also you can use short form like: `Бунин был смел, честен в своих убеждениях.`
As you can see there is no ending at all `смел (ый / ым)`

Comment: so either is fine in speaking?

Comment: it's sounds natural, be sure

Comment: Three variants are correct,  nominative, instrumental and a short form.