# What is correct form - "Был кто" или "Был кем"?

Tags: склонение, essive

I stumble over this one a lot and sort of puts me off a bit. "Я был адвокат", "Петруччо был почтмейстер".
I guess this can be also applied to adjectives like "Я была красивая" or "Я была красивой"?
For some reason I always thought that it should be "Я был адвокатом", "Петруччо был почтмейстером" and "Я была красивой" - but I could be wrong.

Is there a relevant rule?

Comment: https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/15730/declension-after-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB

Comment: hi, this type of question has been dealt with many times here, look for discussions tagged **essive**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's correct to say `быть кем-то/быть чем-то`:

> Он хочет **быть** *учителем*. (**not** он хочет быть *учитель*)
>
> Она *красивая* BUT Она **была** *красивой*. (Она была *красивая* can sometimes be heard but it's less correct than она была *красивой*)
>
> Шоу **будет** зрелищным (I think I've heard шоу будет *зрелищное* but actually, just like in the sentence above, the form of the adjective should be different - зрелищным, not зрелищное)

All in all, when there is a noun or a noun phrase after `быть`, the instrumental case is always used: `быть хорошим человеком`, `быть медсестрой`, etc.

If there is an adjective after `быть`, the instrumental case should be used too. However, in colloquial Russian the nominative case is sometimes used.